# Heat Damage to Laminate Counter-top Near Gas Range

Tags: kitchen-counters, laminate, heat, damage, gas-burner

While deep cleaning our new home, after closing, my wife and discovered what looks like some heat damage to the counter-top next to the gas range.  The house was fully renovated about 2 years ago, just prior to the last owner buying the place, and the range/oven combo was installed as part of the renovation.  I'm new to gas appliances, so I'm somewhat uncertain as to what to expect as to the particulars of certain behaviors of gas appliances.

My thought is that the heat damage may have occurred before the gap covers were installed.  Is that so, or does this look like something that was likely to happen after the covers were installed?

[image: Fully Assembled]
[image: Grill Removed / Gap Covers Exposed]
[image: Gap Covers Removed]
[image: Close-up Damage on Left]
[image: Close-up Damage on Right]

Comment: By raising the stove per Jim Stewart's answer you can eliminate those gaskets if you like. They're in no way necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be insufficient gap and the range appears to be too low. The easiest thing would be to raise the range by 3/4 inch to 1 inch. This might reduce heating of those areas.

EDIT
Might benefit from a stainless steel gap cover like this [https://www.amazon.com/Stainless-Steel-Counter-SILICONE-splatter/dp/B089B6G3XZ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B089B6G3XZ)

Current gap covers appears to be guiding flame onto counter.

Comment: Not sure about the gap thing (mine is the same), but the height is surely an issue. With a wide pan and a high flame the heat would pour out against that edge.

Comment: It could be that the range should be raised by 1.5 inches to get the hotest part of the black top away from the counter.  Is this a free-standing range or a slide in range? Are the sides finished so that the range could be exposed on one or both sides? If so. they are a little wider than a slide in?